# Variable depending on Tab focus

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms

i have question that is bugging me for quite some time but im unable to get this around my mind.

So i have a program that contains 8 tabs, all using same formula for calculating when i click's the button on this page but base value is depending on whitch tab is selected and which button is clicked

variables a1 and a2 are the same values accessing exacly the same database just like b1&b2 and c1&c2 working as comboboxes

```
Private Sub Calculate() Handles button1.Click
value1 = 0.5 
sum1 = a1.selectedValue*b1.SelectedValue*c1.SelectedValue*value1
textbox1.value = sum1.value

Private Sub Calculate2() Handles button2.Click
value2 = 0.55
sum2 = a1.selectedValue*b2.selectedValue*c2.selectedValue*value2
texbox2.value = sum2.value
```

is there any way to make value by depending on the tab that's focused and simplify it? like

```
Private Sub Calculate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click, button2.Click, button3.Click

if tabpage1 is focus then
value = 0.05
elseif tabpage2 is focus then
value = 0.55
end if

if a1 is selected then
a=a1.value
elseif a2.is selected then
a=a2.value
......
endif
.......
sum = a*b*c*value

if tabpage1 is focus then
textbox1.value = sum.value
else
....
endif
```

??
i know code above is far from "simple" and actually the handling buttons in each sub is maybe hmmm... better? Just looking at other perspectives to do this 8 tabs in just one sub

Comment: How about setting values as each tab is clicked? Then call a single calculate method from each button click.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer so if i get it right - it would be function that makes calculation and returning value to right textbox in focused tab?

Comment: I'm not sure that that suggestion really helps because you're just pushing the same problem back to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler.  You've still got to decide what controls to get the data from based on which tab is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that the best solution is something like this:

```
Dim selectedTab = TabControl1.SelectedTab
Dim tb = selectedTab.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().First()
Dim value = CInt(selectedTab.Tag)

'Use tb and value here.
```

You just need to set the `Tag` property of each `TabPage` to the appropriate value and you may need to adjust that second line if there are other `TextBoxes` on each page or it's inside another container.  There's obviously multiple `ComboBoxes` on each page so that part might look like this:

```
Dim cbs = selectedTab.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)().ToArray()
Dim cbb = cbs(0)
Dim cbc = cbs(1)
```

Comment: all works. Thank You. Also cbb cbc are not usable anyway

Answer (score 0):

you can use method  `Focused` or `ActiveControl` or `SelectedTab/Index` as :

```
Private Sub Calculate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click, button2.Click, button3.Click
    If sender Is button1 Then '' Button1 is clicked
     If TabControl1.SelectedTab Is tabpage1 Then
     ''   If tabpage1.Focused OrElse Me.ActiveControl Is tabpage1  Then '' Tabpage1 if focused Or Tabpage1 is Active Control
        ''  Your Code 


     End If
    End If
    If sender Is button2 Then '' Button2 is clicked
        If TabControl1.SelectedTab Is tabpage2 Then
        '' If tabpage2.Focused OrElse Me.ActiveControl Is tabpage2 Then '' Tabpage2 if focused or Tabpage2 is Active Control 
        '' Your Code

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm afraid that that is bad advice.  You wouldn't use `Focused` or `ActiveControl` but rather the `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedTab` property of the `TabControl`.  There's no need for any `If` statements if you do it right though.